# Creating a specific frame

Tags: tcolorbox, report, cropmarks

I need to create this specific frame in my report and I don't know how to even start. Maybe someone knows how to create it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which frame do you mean? The outer one or the inner one? Can you show the code you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make similar crop marks with the `crop` package (I imagine the actual mark design is not so important as it will simply be cut off during production). The grey box is made with the `tcolorbox` package. You will need to adjust the margins/sizes/spacing to fit your needs. As you gave no specific dimensions, I simply chose values that made it look similar to the picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.5in, paperheight=9in, margin=0in,bottom=.5in,top=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[letter,center, noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\crop[cam,axes]
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=lightgray, colback=white, width=3in, sharp corners, boxrule=2mm]
\centering\bigskip
\textbf{\large Tytu\l}\\
\vspace{1in}
\textbf{Autor}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{flushright}
\newpage\crop[off] %To get rid of crop marks on subsequent pages
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much